# Can't find/remove online account from Evolution

Tags: evolution, online-accounts

[image]I have two accounts set up in evolution that I'm not able to remove nor from Evolution itself neither from the online account panel.

In evolution the "Delete" button is disabled when I select those two accounts

In Online Accounts they are not present in the list so I can not remove them.

The accounts I wish to remove are the ones with the half-globe icon

Comment: IMO it should be a bug in *Evolution*. And the *Online* manager account must show you the correct/up-to-date information, that your accounts had been deleted.

Comment: That might be the case but where are those information stored? I mean I should find a config file somewhere to remove manually those accounts, but in ~/.config/evolution there's nothing about that and in gconf-editor I can not find anything either

Comment: open `gconf-editor` and goto `/apps/evolution/mail/accounts` to check for accounts too

Comment: @Sreevisakh I have no /apps/evolution folder under gconf-editor

Answer (score 4):

This is because the default "Ubuntu Online Accounts" (uoa) are different than "Gnome Online Accounts" (goa).

- GOA have a little halfglobe-plug icon
- UOA have a little globe-with-keys icon

Yours are GOA accounts, so they do not show in the UOA (default) online account interface.

Here is how you can get to them.

Go to a command line prompt and run the following, which will bring up the standard System Settings inteface, however it will now contain the GOA and UOA icons.

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

This is clearly confusing as noted in:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1040193

My issue is that GOA is what evolution now uses as the UOA package seems to have disappeared from current saucy as of 3.8.5-1ubuntu3.

evolution-data-server-goa  (adds GOA accounts to evolution, as in your example above).
evolution-data-server-uoa  (adds UOA accounts to evolution, which is more desirable IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. [**Comment 14**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcr/+bug/1044549/comments/14)  by [Mathieu SENSEI (hyu9a)](https://launchpad.net/~hyu9a) on [Bug 1044549](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcr/+bug/1044549) solved it.

The advice there is essentially to check in the file `~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf` and, assuming it contains information (just) about the account or accounts that should be removed, to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Gnome calendar (only a popup at the desktop) was asking frequently for password of an old yahoo account. I tried for a long time to find and remove the account from my installation. All solutions from net didn't help.

Finally I reinstalled Ubuntu completely new with the 20.04LTS version. Of course the problem don't appears any more.

After importing my old E-mails from a Evolution backup, the annoying password request was appearing again. Therefore I searched my Backup for files containing yahoo. 
Actually I found the source for my problem under ~/.config/evolution/sources/
Here some files was containing my old yahoo account. After removing the corresponding files the popup was gone.

greetings

Answer (score -1):

killall evolution &&
rm -r ~/.cache/evolution

greetings

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please refrain from 1 line answers. Explain why this will work, in addition to the command (and if any source, cite, but do not just post links either)

Comment: Not only is 1 line, but also doesn't work.