# Whenever I delete Jabber and Yahoo from my online accounts list, they reappear

Tags: gnome, authentication, online-accounts, yahoo

Whenever I delete Jabber and Yahoo from my online accounts list, they reappear after a restart.

[image]

Because of this, whenever I open login, I get a large number of popups asking for my Yahoo password:

[image]

I don't mind if Yahoo! says in the list, but I really need these popups to go. Even if I type my password for each one, they open up next time I log in.

I'm using Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04. This didn't happen before in Unity, but I can't switch back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've a good news and a bad news for you. :)

Good news, this annoyance can be removed. The account information is stored in `~/.config/libaccounts-glib/`. Just delete every file in there. All your accounts will be gone on reboot. Then you can recreate the one you want.

Bad news, this seems to be an old bug which is not yet cured. [Checkout here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245652/cant-delete-facebook-and-google-in-online-accounts-where-is-the-config-file-fo).

I would suggest you update your gnome version or [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/) with Gnome.

Comment: Didn't work, the popup still appears, even though they have finally disappeared...

Comment: Interesting. i believed the Calendar account would be controlled by the Online Accounts settings. But they are different.

Comment: Stop goa daemon by `killall goa-daemon`. Delete the files in `~/.config/goa-1.0` and `~/.config/evolution` as well. The reason why Gnome does not do that automatically is not known. Check their permissions before deleting. I think you'll find this relevant (http://askubuntu.com/questions/270795/cant-find-remove-online-account-from-evolution)

Comment: Yep - got rid of the notifications!